Regarding purity of clothes
I usually wash mani or madhi with my hands before putting the clothes in washing machine. But what happened is my mother one day she put all my undergarments in the washing machine and they are stained with mani, Mazi and some urine also. After the clothes washed I see the traces of Mazi. I am certain that it was traces of Mazi. And I also have seen the substances of mani.
Now I know that sprinkling water on Mazi is sufficient.
And mani is pure.
But I am getting this doubt because of urine. Because usually what I do is when some mani and Mazi is discharged I do not do istinja after urinating.
So the problem is urine drops make the mani and Mazi impure.
Doubt is that overwhelming with water makes those traces of mani and Mazi pure or not? As I seen the substances of mani and assuming that because of urine drops it becomes impure and because it is not removed from the cloth and still impure.
Please guide me in this matter.
